# Read from CSV and convert to dictionary

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file having the below values. I would like to read CSV and create a dictionary in C#. Dictionary Key = Name and Value in `List<Product>` such as `Dictionary<string, List<Product>>`

Note: In CSV, the Name can be duplicated (laptop). So I have to get a distinct Name first to get the key for the dictionary and build the Product list.

For example, in below sample data dictionary will have two key

1. laptop (with two values)
2. mobile (with one value)

I have found the below code but not sure how to build a dictionary based on the above requirements.

```cs
var dict = File.ReadLines("textwords0.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);
```

```
Name     Code  Price
laptop , 9999, 100.00
Mobile , 7777, 500.00
laptop , 9999, 100.00
```

```cs
public class Product 
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string code {get;set;}
    string Price {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Are the keys like model numbers or something, or literally the words "laptop" and "mobile"?

Comment: Did you try googling if there are any libraries available for the same?

Comment: You might want to read the file line by line. And for every line check if the key exist in your dictionary.. If not then create new list with the product details and add the list to the dictionary with the productname key. Else add the product to the list which is already there in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dictionary key is non-duplicate, you need a `.GroupBy()` to group by `Name` **first**.

1. `.GroupBy()` - Group by `Name`, and return an `IEnumerable` of anonymous type with `{ string Name, List<Product> Products }`.
2. `.ToDictionary()` - Convert previous `IEnumerable` data to key-value pair.

```cs
var dict = File.ReadLines("textwords0.csv")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(
        x => x[0],
        (k, x) => new
        {
            Name = k,
            Products = x.Select(y => new Product
                            {
                                Name = y[0],
                                code = y[1],
                                Price = y[2]
                            })
                        .ToList()
        })      
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Products);
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATR5Lz)